# HAProxy load balancing with tomcat SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl, haproxy

I have 2 tomcat7 instances (on 2 separate VMs) with SSL, and I want to use haproxy as a load balancer for them.
I'm unsure exactly how to do this, but I tried installing haproxy 1.5 with open ssl (and compiled with `USE_OPENSSL=yes`) and used a similar configuration to here: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/05/configure-haproxy-to-load-balance-sites-with-ssl/

```
frontend https_frontend  
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/keystore
  mode http
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend web_server

backend web_server
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server s1 vm1:8443 check cookie s1
  server s2 vm2:8443  check cookie s2
```

I get the following error when starting haproxy:

```
'bind' only supports the 'transparent', 'defer-accept', 'name', 'id', 'mss' and 'interface' options.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not compiled HAProxy with SSL support.
Please add USE_OPENSSL=1 when building HAProxy. Note that it requires libssl-dev package to be installed.

Baptiste