# SSL certificates for HAProxy with tomcat - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I'm trying to haproxy work in ssl mode with 2 tomcat instances on different VMs (see my previous question: [HAProxy load balancing with tomcat SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843301/haproxy-load-balancing-with-tomcat-ssl)).
Currently, I managed to get haproxy to work with the following configuration:

```
defaults
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    option tcplog

frontend ft_test
    mode http
    bind 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl crt haproxy.pem
    timeout client 120000ms
    default_backend bk

backend bk
    mode http
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    server s1 vm1:80 cookie JSESSIONID_SERVER_1 check maxconn 32    
    server s2 vm2:80 cookie JSESSIONID_SERVER_2 check maxconn 32
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout server 120000ms
```

haproxy.pem is a file I copied from here (for testing purposes): http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/09/04/howto-ssl-native-in-haproxy/

When I change the port from 80 to 8443 on the VMs, and I try to access https://haproxy.vm.ip:8443 (same as I did with the 80 port), I get a: `502 Bad Gateway` error in my browser.
I'm guessing this has something to do with the ssl certificates, but I'm not sure how to solve this (these issues are new to me, and I wasn't able to find much information).

The server.xml for each tomcat VM (they're the same):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
            keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/keystore"
            keystorePass="password" />
```

Do I need to use the same certificate here as in the haproxy configuration? I tried that but it doesn't seem to work, and I didn't find an example for haproxy with a keystore file either.

So, help? Ideas? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue -

I was never able to get 1.5 to correctly and consistently process SSL traffic without receiving intermittent 502's and 503's.

We ended up using stunnel - http://www.stunnel.org/

Very simple to setup and configure. HAproxy just responds on port 80 and forwards over 443 so that internal traffic remains encrypted.

Here's a sample stunnel.conf file to start from:

```
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
cert=/etc/stunnel/wildcard.pem
setuid = root
setgid = root
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
output = /var/log/stunnel.log

[service1]
    accept = 10.0.0.10:443
    connect = 10.0.0.10:80
    TIMEOUTclose = 0

[service2]
    accept = 10.0.0.11:443
    connect = 10.0.0.11:80
    TIMEOUTclose = 0
```